# how to turn an time.asctime string to relative time (e.g. 40 minutes ago)

Tags: python, time

I have a time string generated by git python using:

```
for com in git.Repo().iter_commits():
    print(time.asctime(time.localtime(com.committed_date)))
```

is it possible to reach something like a relative time stamp, like I can get from git log using some of its pretty formats?

```
19b9451 - naming (6 hours ago) <myname>
```

generated by

```
 git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```

Looked a bit on humanize, but couldn't find a way to do this simply. *Looking for an idiomatic way to do so. I guess I can hack away with datetime many functions, but I prefer a simple one-liner solution, if possible*

Answer (score 2):

Logic:

1. Transform the string into a `datetime.datetime`object.
2. Get the current `datetime.datetime` object. Clue: look for `now`.
3. Substract these 2 objects to get a `datetime.timedelta` object.
4. Round the `datetime.timedelta` object.
5. Print the result.

If you find problems trying to follow my steps, post your code and we will help you.